# HSQLDB org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException on complex select

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hsqldb

I have a query that runs fine in Oracle, but I receive a `org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException` when attempting to run the same query in HSQLDB (using the Oracle compatibility mode).

Here is the query in question:

```
select 
    Orders.id,
    (select sum(decode(Orders.status, 'C', Orderlines.qty, 0)) 
     from Orderlines where orderId = Orders.id
    ) as "productQuantity"
from Orders
join Orderlines on Orders.id = Orderlines.orderId
where Orders.customerId = ?
group by Orders.id, Orders.status
```

Here is the root of the stack trace

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.result.Result.newErrorResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.result.Result.newErrorResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.getValue(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Expression.getValue(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionOp.getValue(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionAggregate.updateAggregatingValue(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.buildResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.getResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementQuery.getResult(Unknown Source)
... 63 more
```

If I simplify the query slightly by removing the `decode` clause, HSQLDB can handle it.

```
select 
    Orders.id,
    (select sum(Orders.status) 
     from Orderlines where orderId = Orders.id
    ) as "productQuantity"
from Orders
join Orderlines on Orders.id = Orderlines.orderId
where Orders.customerId = ?
group by Orders.id, Orders.status
```

Is this a known limitation of HSQLDB?

Any ideas how to get past this?  I'm attempting to use HSQLDB for unit tests so modifying the query isn't really an option unless the solution also works for Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of HSQLDB. You can try `CASE Order.status WHEN 'C' THEN Orderlines.qty ELSE 0 END` instead and see if it works.